# Keeping Object references when serializing and deserializing in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

Alright guys/gals, This is my first post and I have searched and tried many things, so my apologies if this is a stupid question.

The classes mentioned below; DataDirectory, LogicPackage, and DataStream, are part of my class library in VB.Net. This is a simplified example code that I will serialize:

```
Dim DD as new DataDirectory
DD.masterpath = "C:\MasterPath"
Dim L as new LogicPackage
For x = 1 to 5
    Dim DS as new DataStream
    DS.number = x
    DS.DataDirectory = DD
    L.DataStreams.Add(DS)
Next

L.Serialize(Path) ''This serializes just fine
```

''The problem arises when I deserialize, A new DataDirectory will be instantiated ''for every DataStream, rather than all of the DataStreams referencing the same ''DataStream instance.

```
Dim NewL as LogicPackage = Deserialize(Path)
```

''L will have 5 DataStreams that all reference one DataDirectory

''NewL will have 5 DataStreams that reference 5 DataDirectory instances

Is there some sort of serialization method that will preserve the object references? I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: What serializer are you using currently? reference tracking is included in many, but is often "opt in".

Comment: This is the code for the serializer: XmlSerializer(GetType(LogicPackage))
 Dim writer As New StreamWriter(filename)
serializer.Serialize(writer, Me)


    End Sub @MarcGravell

Comment: so: `XmlSerializer` then; sadly, `XmlSerializer` *does not* support this. You could try `DataContractSerializer` [which does support this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290456/serializing-cyclic-object-references-using-datacontractserializer-not-working) via `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`, but: the format will be different

Comment: Thank you Marc! I will look into it.